# Dynamic module/service configuration and AOT

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I need to have some Angular services configured dynamically, depending on a runtime switch. In days before AOT, I got it to work using the following code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: []
})
export class MyModule {
  static forRoot(config: MyConfiguration): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
        SomeService,
        {
          provide: SomeOtherService,
          useFactory: (some: SomeService, http: Http) => {
            switch (config.type) {
              case 'cloud':
                return new SomeOtherService(new SomethingSpecificForCloud());
              case 'server':
                return new SomeOtherService(new SomethingSpecificForServer());
            }
          },
          deps: [SomeService, Http]
        },

      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Then in my `AppModule` I would import this as `MyModule.forRoot(myConfig)`.

As I updated CLI and Angular, this no longer compiles, because it cannot be statically analyzed. I understand why, but I am still not sure what the correct way to solve it is.

Have I abused this `forRoot()` approach in the first place? How do you write modules so that depending on a runtime switch, they produce different services?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found one way to achieve it: Expose the configuration via a provider, then have injected to a "static" factory function. The code above would look like this:

```
// Necessary if MyConfiguration is an interface
export const MY_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('my.config');

// Static factory function
export function someOtherServiceFactory(config: MyConfiguration,some: SomeService, http: Http) {
  switch (config.type) {
    case 'cloud':
      return new SomeOtherService(new SomethingSpecificForCloud());
    case 'server':
      return new SomeOtherService(new SomethingSpecificForServer());
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: []
})
export class MyModule {
  static forRoot(config: MyConfiguration): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
        SomeService,
        { provide: MY_CONFIG, useValue: config },
        {
          provide: SomeOtherService,
          useFactory: someOtherServiceFactory,
          deps: [MY_CONFIG, SomeService, Http]
        },

      ]
    };
  }
}
```

It works and all, but I would still be very interested in knowing whether this is actually a good idea, or if I'm doing something terribly wrong and should be taking a completely different approach to solving this problem.

---

I found another solution:

1. Use Angular CLI environments.
2. Create an abstract classes/interfaces for the services with different implementations or dependencies for different environments.
3. Export the right type from each enviromnent file (who said it has to only be a plain JS object?).
4. In the module provider definition, import *from the environment*.
5. At compile time, CLI environments will make the right thing get linked.

More information and sample project at [my blog](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2017/07/23/environment-specific-modules-services-and-components-in-angular/).

Comment: I think this is the only option. 1 remark: from v4 you should use `InjectionToken` instead of `OpaqueToken`.